# How do I open a file with unknown associations in iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uidocumentinteraction

I think it's rather impossible, but will ask anyway. My application uses file association to open some types of files. What I need is to make file associations within my app. For example I have some files in my app's Documents folder and when user wants to open that it would be a great idea to ask him in which application he would like it to open (like Mail app does).

It can possibly be done with URL schemes, but if I don't know what applications user has, it can't be used. So, is there any way to use the device's file associations within an application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at [Document Interaction Programming Topics for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010403). It explains how you can use the UIDocumentInteractionController class to present the user a list of apps which support a given file.

Comment: Thank you! But that file is copied in that application's documents folder, doesn't it? So I jave no control over files changes made by this application? Or maybe there is some way to get that file from application after editing(for example by text editor)?

Comment: The UIDocumentInteractionController will take care of passing the file (or path, I'm not sure) to the app chosen by the user, even if it lives in your app's Document directory.

Comment: Yes. But if app changes the file, than I have no opportunity to access this changed file, because it is in the other application's documents folder. Am i right?

Comment: Correct. It will send a copy of the file to the application the user select.  Once it there, only the selected application can read/write the file.